# Monotone Convergence Theorem in Measure Theory.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, monotone-functions

My textbook defined M.C.T. by

for $\{f_k\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E\subset\mathbb{R}^n$,

1. If $f_k\nearrow{}f~~a.e.$ on $E$ and there exists $\phi\in{}L(E)$ such that $f_k\ge\phi~~a.e.$ on $E$ for all $k$, then $$\int_E{}f_k\to\int_E{}f$$
2. If $f_k\searrow{}f~~a.e.$ on $E$ and there exists $\phi\in{}L(E)$ such that $f_k\le\phi~~a.e.$ on $E$ for all $k$, then $$\int_E{}f_k\to\int_E{}f$$

---

In the M.C.T. in the sense of the sequence of real numbers, when a sequence is ***increasing*** and bounded ***above***, then its supremum is the limit. Conversely, when a sequence is ***decreasing*** and bounded ***below***, then its infimum is the limit.

---

I do not understand why $f_k$ is bounded ***below*** by $\phi$ although $f_k$ are monotonically ***increasing*** functions, i.e. $f_k\le{}f_{k+1}$. Conversely, I do not understand why $f_k$ is bounded ***above*** by $\phi$ although $f_k$ are monotonically ***decreasing*** functions, i.e. $f_k\ge{}f_{k+1}$.

Comment: Looking at the increasing case: $+\infty$ is a perfectly sensible limit, pointwise for the functions as well as for the integrals. The condition $f_k \geqslant \phi$ guarantees that $\int_E f_k$ makes sense, i.e. is not of the from $+\infty + (-\infty)$. $f_k \geqslant \phi$ with $\phi \in L(E)$ says $\int_E f_k^- < +\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Can I ask what is difference between $\ge$ and $\geqslant$? I know the meaning is same because I already asked here. I want to know when $\ge$ has to be used and when $\geqslant$ does.

Comment: The difference is only typographical. In my eyes, $\geqslant$ simply looks (much) better. So I tend to use that.

Comment: If e.g. $f_k=-\frac1{k}$ and an infinite measure then $f_k$ is increasing and has $f=0$ as limit. But $\int f_k=-\infty$ for each $k$ while $\int f=0$. The bounding $\phi$ allows you to work with $f_k-\phi$ wich is nonnegative a.e.

Comment: @DanielFischer You mean if $f_k$ is not restricted by $\phi$, then $f_k=f_k^+ - f_k^-$ can be $\infty - \infty$. So, $\phi$ prevent from happening this case???

Comment: Yes, and the limit function can also not have $\int_E f^+ = \int_E f^- = +\infty$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am impressed with your greatest answer. Thank you very much. Because of this, I spend a lot of time. M.C.T,, U.C.T., D.C.T., and B.C.T. Ah~~~ Thank you

Comment: @drhab I was also wondering why $\phi\in{}L(E)$ is adopted, instead of using just a finite real number $M$. Your example solved my curiosity. Thank you.